# How to Get an Atmotube Out of Flashing Mode

Tags: bluetooth

I bought an Atmotube (BT LE device to be used with an Android phone).

The device seems to be stuck in flashing mode ("DfuMode") according to output from

```
hcitool lescan
```

on my Linux PC.

Do you know of any way of resetting this device back to the default firmware?

I asked their support but I hope that someone has some info about this. The device seems poorly designed if it can get corrupted - I don't remember doing any firmware update on it but it ran out of power at some point.

(I don't know where else to ask this.)

Comment: Is the device currently paired with your Linux PC?

Comment: No it's not. I can connect to it using one of the bluez tools that allows me to browse what is available on the device.

Comment: Then it'll be unlikely to find an answer here. Super User is for personal computers, and we try to help with peripherals when the issue is mostly on the computer. With the issue being on the BT device, we may not be able to get you a good answer. I would continue to pursue official support options, especially if the device is newer.

Comment: No worries. :) I know this. I hoped that someone had a device like this (since who in the right mind buys tech toys like this but people like us ;-)) and experience similar problems.

Comment: I know, right? Yea, it's worth a try, but unlikely. I haven't looked for these, but there may be forums focusing on Bluetooth devices or mobile accessories that might have a more knowledgeable population.

Answer (score 0):

In case some one else has the same problem.

I got in touch with the developers and they sent me this (after a lengthy e-mail exchange): https://gist.github.com/wojciiii/b89dc9f51b36d774863560c44c4b398f

One can use the nRF Toolbox android app to flash certain Nordic Semiconductor based devices. I flashed the device using the provided information/firmware and it started working.